# Use of unresolved identifier 'kCAFillModeForwards'

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, cabasicanimation, caanimation

When I try to set `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards` Xcode can't compile and display an error. "**Use of unresolved identifier 'kCAFillModeForwards'"**.

I've already used this in previous projects without any issues, did somebody already encountered this behaviour?

```
func animateGradient() {
        currentGradient += 1
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: Animation.keyPath)
        animation.duration = animationDuration
        animation.toValue = currentGradientSet()
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.delegate = self
        gradient.add(animation, forKey: Animation.key)
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 10.0 beta 2, Swift 4.2 and I build it for iOS 12

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That constant has been removed in favor of a [`forwards`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfillmode/1427658-forwards) property on the `CAMediaTimingFillMode` type. As of Swift 4.2 the same thing is written as:

```
animation.fillMode = .forwards
```

---

That said, the combination of a forward fill mode and not removing the animation when it completes is often misused in an attempt to make an animation "stick"/"remain". Unless you are animating the removal of a layer, a cleaner solution is to update the layer to the new value and add an animation—which is removed when it completes—to transition from the previous value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I was searching the conversion of .forwards to Swift 4 and is -> kCAFillModeForwards

Comment: Thanks for specifying that this change was since 4.2. Fixed my problem.